# How do I scroll page-wise in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, scrolling

Any time I use Page Up/Down part of the previous page remains on screen, like so:

[image: 1]

How do I fix this so that only a single page is shown at a time?

Comment: What's wrong in the screenshot?

Comment: It is showing zoom at 100%. This is good for reading text but Page Up won't skip exactly 1 page at a time (unless your screen happens to be so large that 100% zoom perfectly fits 1 page on the screen). I have a 25" widescreen LCD and for me "Whole page" sets zoom to 80%.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is probably to be expected, unless you set the zoom level so the page fits the screen:

[image]

Comment: thank's your help but unfortunately no change ....http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/4070/jflv.jpg

Comment: I just tested it on my Word 2010 and it works for me. Are you sure you set page zoom to "whole page"? In your screenshot it shows "100%".

Comment: yes, in new screenshoot is "whole page"(60% ) but nothing change..

Comment: Hmm. Well if it still doesn't work then I'm out of ideas unfortunately, because I can't recreate the issue. Hopefully someone else can recreate your problem on their Word 2010.

Comment: Thank's Your help ,unfortunately this happens with other documents too.

Comment: @herosz, Can't reproduce the issue either. Can you spot anything different about the documents where the scrolling doesn't work properly to those where is does?

Comment: I would suggest doing a reinstall of Word, as what you are experiencing does not sound normal and could suggest corruption of the application. You could probably fix it in 10 minutes if you go ahead with an uninstall, reboot, reinstall.